# How to automatically indent in VSCode in a switch-case statement?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

It's a bit frustrating that there are a lot of things that vscode does automatically but when using a switch-case statement it doesn't automatically indent after the colon.
This is what I get if I were to type without interfering

```
int x = 32;
switch (x){
    case 33:
    break;
    case 32:
    break;
    default:
}
```

And this is what I would like the to see

```
int x = 32;
switch (x){
    case 33:
        break;
    case 32:
        break;
    default:
}
```

Comment: If visual studio does not indent the above code in the way you want as you type it, then this is the default indentation of VS.

Comment: Personally I align my `case` labels with the `switch` and closing brace. Horses for courses you know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Clang Format for customizable formatting rules

For any C++ formatting needs I would recommend using [Clang Format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html), which can be seamlessly integrated into VS Code.

In you example you may use the `IndentCaseLabels` [style option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html):

> #### IndentCaseLabels (bool)
>
> Indent case labels one level from the switch statement.
>
> When `false`, use the same indentation level as for the switch statement. Switch statement body is always indented one level more
>   than case labels (except the first block following the case label,
>   which itself indents the code - unless IndentCaseBlocks is enabled).
>
> ```
> false:                                 true:
> switch (fool) {                vs.     switch (fool) {
> case 1:                                  case 1:
>   bar();                                   bar();
>   break;                                   break;
> default:                                 default:
>   plop();                                  plop();
> }                                      }
> ```

Applied to your example:

```
//  IndentCaseLabels: true
int x = 32;
switch (x) {
  case 33:
    void();
    break;
  case 32:
    break;
  default:
}

//  IndentCaseLabels: false
int x = 32;
switch (x) {
case 33:
  void();
  break;
case 32:
  break;
default:
}
```

## Integration of Clang Format into VS Code

Citing [*Edit C++ in Visual Studio Code* from the VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide) [**emphasis** mine]:

> [...]
>
> #### Code formatting
>
> The **C/C++ extension for Visual Studio Code** supports source code
>   formatting using `clang-format` which is **included with the extension**.
>
> You can format an entire file with Format Document (Ctrl+Shift+I) or
>   just the current selection with Format Selection (Ctrl+K Ctrl+F) in
>   right-click context menu. **You can also configure auto-formatting** with
>   the following settings:
>
> - `editor.formatOnSave` - **to format when you save your file**.
> - `editor.formatOnType` - to format as you type (triggered on the `;` character).
>
> By default, the clang-format style is set to "file" which means **it looks for a `.clang-format` file inside your workspace**. If the `.clang-format` file is found, formatting is applied according to the settings specified in the file. **If no `.clang-format` file is found in your workspace**, formatting is applied based on a default style specified in the `C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle` setting instead. Currently, **the default formatting style is "Visual Studio"** which is an approximation of the default code formatter in Visual Studio.
>
> [...]

Comment: That's a good starting point but I need specific instructions on how to integrate it. None of the sources give any explicit advices to that. From what I've understood I need to install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format and then make a file named `.clang-format` in the root directory of the workspace and add `IndentCaseLabels: true` in there but that doesn't work.

Comment: @Managor before attempting to customize your `.clang-format` file make sure that clang-format is even invoked (e.g. on save). See also [Clang Format's documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for details. I'm using Emacs myself, but imho the instructions for how to integrate it (as linked to above) seems quite clear (given you've also read up some on Clang Format itself), and I know I used them myself (a few months ago) to help a colleague using VS Code to get Clang Format setup.

Comment: Ah, `editor.formatOnType` needed to be set in the vscode settings themselves.