# why it is not showing default indentation in switch function while applying case?

Tags: c++, syntax, switch-statement, case, indentation

[image]

Why it is not showing any indentation after "case" . What should I do so that it starts showing proper indentation .

Comment: This has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727685/how-to-automatically-indent-in-vscode-in-a-switch-case-statement It is not a C++ "issue" but and editor "issue" :) It is how switch in C++ is handled by default in VCS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically indent in VSCode in a switch-case statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60727685/how-to-automatically-indent-in-vscode-in-a-switch-case-statement)